# How to use regex to parse the Tablename from a file in PySpark databricks notebook

Tags: regex, pyspark, databricks, parquet

I'm trying to get the table name from parquet files using regex. I'm using the following code to attempt this but the `ctSchema` dataframe doesn't seem to run causing the job to return 0 results.

```
    ci= spark.createDataFrame(data=[("","","")], schema=ciSchema)
    files=dbutils.fs.ls('a filepath goes here')
    
    results = {}
    is_error = False
    
    for fi in files:
          try:
            dataFile = spark.read.parquet(fi.path)
            ctSchema = spark.createDataFrame(data = dataFile.dtypes, schema = tSchema).withColumn("TableName", regexp_extract(input_file_name(),"([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_shard_\d+_of_\d+\.parquet",1), lit(fi.name))
            ci = ci.union(ctSchema)
          except Exception as e:
            results[fi.name] = f"Error: {e}"
            is_error = True
```

Comment: Why do you have to read files individually? Spark should be able to read all files at once. And try to [minimize your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus on the question

Comment: Just starting out with Spark so not too sure on proper syntax yet. Made a few edits to focus on the main issue of the code

Comment: Try just this `df = spark.read.parquet('a filepath goes here')` for file reading. And I'm guessing your main question is about `regexp_extract`? Can you provide sample input and your expected output?

Comment: Sample input would be TCP_119Customer_page_1_of_1.parquet so output would be 119Customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_shard_\d+_of_\d+\.parquet` is incorrect, try this one instead `[a-zA-Z0-9]+_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_page_\d+_of_\d+\.parquet`.

First, I used `page_` instead of `shard_`, which matches your file name.

Second, you don't want to group `([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` which would match `TCP_119Customer`. You only want the second group, so change it to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` will fix the issue.

Comment: Figured out the issue on my end, the stuff I sent over were just samples the naming of the file was irrelevant but it was a separate mistake dealing with a missing variable.